# BigDecimal validation raises an error on non numeric values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To validate the price we require, we use the following

```
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01, less_than_or_equal_to: 2000}
```

It works fine until someone tries to enter a string (in this example "FREE").
This returns the error:

```
invalid value for BigDecimal(): "FREE"
```

Is there a clean way of validating this without returning a 500 error?

Comment: Can you give some more context on how you're running this code? If I try to run this validation on a model with a string it works as expected and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Perhaps, you're trying to cast the string to a BigDecimal in a custom setter method? Can you provide the code which raises this exception?

Comment: There is no custom setters, it's merely just the snippet above and a presence validator @Teoulas

Comment: did you try the solution I've suggested?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it did not work

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help someone who stumbled on such case, seems like upgrading the `BigDecimal` gem solves the issue

`gem "bigdecimal", ">= 1.3.2"`

Reference: https://jamescrisp.org/2017/09/26/bigdecimal-fix-for-rails-4-with-ruby-2-4/